# Android Studio no USB devices detected

Tags: android, android-studio, miui, redmi-device

I'm trying to run my android app on my Redmi Note 5 china rom MIUI 10. But it's not showing on android studio. I've enabled USB debugging and install via USB and turned of MIUI optimization. But it still isn't working. 
PS: I use windows 8.1

Comment: Android Studio is available in available for Linux, Windows and Mac. It would help that you can tell us what your operating system is.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you would need to install the appropriate driver for your Android device. See https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb for more details how to do this.